# Android screen size and density. How to choose text size?

Tags: java, android, android-screen-support

I'm trying to understand multi-screen support in android. Yes I read the documentation, but still have few questions.

As I understand i need to create drawables for each density, but what to do with text size?

I want to set title on my activity which will fit any screen (need to big big enough and don't warp the text)
I test in on my Nexus7 (large screen) and it looks good with `android:textSize="100dp"'`

When i launch it on emulator with 'normal screen' size i get very big text.
So is it right solution to make layouts for each screen size?

```
'layout'
'layout-large'
'layout-small'
....
```

and just make `android:textSize="70dp"` for normal screen and `android:textSize="50dp"` for small screen?

And another one question how to test all this in more efficient way?
I need to create emulators with? Where to get parameters with which create emulators to get this results?

1. XLarge screen

   - ldpi
   - mdpi
   - tvdpi
   - hdpi
   - xhdpi
2. Large screen

   - ldpi
   - mdpi
   - tvdpi
   - hdpi
   - xhdpi
3. Medium screen

   - ldpi
   - mdpi
   - tvdpi
   - hdpi
   - xhdpi
4. Small screen

   - ldpi
   - mdpi
   - tvdpi
   - hdpi
   - xhdpi

Answer (score 2):

For text size you should use `sp` units. [Docs say](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also
>   scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
>   this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and the user's preference.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand i need to create drawables for each density, but what to do with text size?

As WebnetMobile indicates, you start by using `sp`, as this takes the user's choice of font scale into account. However, you may need more than that.

> So is it right solution to make layouts for each screen size?

I would recommend using dimension resources, with different definitions for the text size dimension as needed for your different scenarios.

Where possible, though, design your UI to be more flexible about font sizes. Again, if you use `sp`, the *user* can change the size of the text on Android 4.0+, to make it bigger or smaller, to help them read the text on their device. Hence, you cannot assume that you are in complete control over the size of the font, and therefore need to design accordingly. This is not significantly different than designing a Web site that takes into account users' adjustments to font size in their browser.

> And another one question how to test all this in more efficient way? I need to create emulators with?

You will need emulators or devices for whatever scenarios concern you.

> Where to get parameters with which create emulators to get this results?

On the (now-current) R21 versions of the tools, you set the screen size and density in the Device Definitions tab of the AVD Manager, then create AVDs based upon those definitions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to test in different screens and density you can create emulators with different combinations. When we create the emulator device we can set the Density (Abstracted LCD density under hardware).

```
  ldpi - 120 
  mdpi - 160
  hdpi - 240
  xhdpi - 320
```

You can set the screen size also while start the emulator